# Angular APP_INITIALIZER circular dependencies at runtime

Tags: angular, circular-dependency

I have a circular dependency (**at run-time**!) problem, which I don't see how to resolve.

I have registered an APP_INITIALIZER load function, which loads a config.json file. This config file contains among others the `LogLevel` for `NGXLogger`.
The config file is loaded through angular's `HttpClient`.

Besides that, I have registered an `HttpInterceptor`, which uses the `NGXLogger`.

It seems that angular tries to resolve everything in this order:

1. `APP_INITIALIZER`, so run this function first
2. Load function of the initializer triggers a `http` call, so first run through the interceptor
3. Load dependencies of the `HttpInterceptor` => `NGXLogger`
4. Configure providers for the `NGXLogger` => based on the configuration file in `APP_INITIALIZER`
5. Throw error, config is undefined

How can I resolve this circular dependencies? Is there a way to completely skip the interceptor on the `APP_INITIALIZER` http call?

CoreModule.ts:

```
export function appConfigFactory(configService: AppConfigService) {
  return () => configService.load();
}

export function loggerConfigFactory(configService: AppConfigService): {
  return () => {
    level: (NgxLoggerLevel as any)[configService.config.logLevel] || NgxLoggerLevel.ERROR,
  };
}

@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [{
    provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
    useFactory: appConfigFactory,
    deps: [AppConfigService],
    multi: true
  }, {
    provide: NgxLoggerConfig,
    useFactory: loggerConfigFactory,
    deps: [AppConfigService]
  }]
})
export class CoreModule {}
```

AppConfigService.ts:

```
export class AppConfigService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  load() {
    return this.http
      .get<AppConfig>(`/assets/configuration/${environment.configFile}`)
      .pipe(
        tap((config: any) => {
          this.config = config;
        })
      )
      .toPromise();
  }
}
```

FakeBackendInterceptor:

```
@Injectable()
export class FakeBackendInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private configService: AppConfigService, private logger: NGXLogger) { }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        // config is undefined here the first time
        if (!this.configService.config || !this.configService.config.mock === 'true') {
            return next.handle(request);
        }
        this.logger.info('Intercepting request with mock');
        // do things
        ...
        return next.handle(request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `HttpBackend` to skip the interceptor in the config service

```
constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private httpBackend: HttpBackend) { }
```

And in the load method

```
const httpClient = new HttpClient(this.httpBackend);
httpClient.get<AppConfig>(`/assets/configuration/${environment.configFile}`)
.pipe(
    tap((config: any) => {
      this.config = config;
    })
  )
  .toPromise();
```

Comment: Awesome! I first thought, this is just a workaround. But googling on this solution actually lead me to a github thread which also discusses my specific use-case. Thank you!

Comment: For reference, [this github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20203)